# PrimeNG Angular 10 - How to add an icon in p-autoComplete

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

Is there a way to add an icon inside primeng p-autoComplete?

```
<div class="p-mr-2 p-input">
   <p-autoComplete styleClass="p-autocomplete-list-item" [(ngModel)]="location"
     [suggestions]="results" field="name" placeholder="Search location"> 
   </p-autoComplete>
 </div>
```

I am looking for a way to add a location icon inside this auto-complete element

Comment: See the section labeled Templating here: https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/autocomplete

Comment: @R.Richards the templating is talking about the dropdown of autocomplete. I am looking for an icon in the input box just to indicate that is a location search field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PrimeNg provides [InputGroup](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/inputgroup) option which can be used to add icon for input.

```
<div class="p-mr-2 p-input">
  <div class="p-inputgroup">
    <span class="p-inputgroup-addon">$</span>
    <p-autoComplete styleClass="p-autocomplete-list-item" [(ngModel)]="location [suggestions]="results" field="name" placeholder="Search location"> 
    </p-autoComplete>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here instead of `$` add required location icon.

Answer (score 1):

there is a **Property** "**dropdownIcon**" takes the name of an icon the default
"pi pi-chevron-down".

```
 <p-autoComplete
              [group]="true"
              field="label"
              [multiple]="true"
              [dropdown]="true"
              dropdownIcon="pi pi-search"
            >
```