# How to add a search icon in primeng autocomplete just the way google search have?

Tags: angular, autocomplete, primeng

I have to add search icon to prime-ng autocomplete but unable to do that

```
<p-autocomplete
placeholder="Search"
[suggestions]="items">
<p-template let-item template="item">
      <div>
        <span>{{ item }}</span>
      </div>
</p-template>
<p-autocomplete>
```

Comment: what do you want to do on that search icon?

Comment: It will be there on display that's it. No usage of it.

Comment: so why don't you put p-autcomplete inside a div with position relative, and setup a pseudo element i.e. after on that div with that icon and right position as 0?

Comment: and which version of primeng you are using?

Comment: I have tried your approach but I want the icon to be part of p-autocomplete so that css applied to rendered input element will be uniform throughout. I don't want to add additional css for the icon part too. If icon is he part of autocomplete then automatically the icon will take css styling of autocomplete.

Comment: Why not add a global css file that will add the icon to all the autocomplete elements you use in the application (or limit it to certain elements using a dedicated class you can place on them)?

Answer (score 0):

there is a Property **"dropdownIcon"** which takes the name of an icon the default "pi pi-chevron-down".
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73788813/12271506